# Simple Case statement returns ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case, ora-00937

When I try to execute following block, it returns ORA-00937. Can someone help what is happening here?

```
select case when count(1)=0 then (select 0 from dual)
          else (select 1 from dual )
          end  test1 
from dual;
```

This is just simplified example I tried and I am facing this error. I have a rather complex query which has similar structure but failing with same error.

Answer (score 1):

The error got resolved after using group by on one the columns in my **complex** query.

For example, in the above given example if you add following group by, it starts working.

```
select case when count(1)=0 then (select 0 from dual)
          else (select 1 from dual )
          end  test1 
from dual group by dummy;
```

**Note** : The column on which we are applying group by, must have same value for all the rows .

Sorry for being late to respond on this. Thanks everyone for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation queries are not friendly to subqueries.  You probably already know what you can write:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as test1
from dual;
```

Or more concisely:

```
select sign(count(*)) as test1
from dual;
```

Comment: The OP said this is a much simplified version of something more complicated. The diagnosis is probably correct, but the fix is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message points specifically to the 0 in `select 0 from dual`; why it points to that specifically is not clear, since 0 itself is a constant (and therefore it is always a GROUP BY expression, no matter what else is happening). It is more likely that Gordon Linoff is right: the scalar subquery itself is the issue, since Oracle doesn't evaluate it "now" (at compilation time), it just says "I can't assume it will turn out to be a constant". In which case the error message should point to the beginning of the subquery, not to the 0 in it. Oh well...

Anyway: if you want to rewrite it in an equivalent way, that will be valid from the outset, you could do something like this:

```
select case when exists (select * from dual) then [the first thing]
       else [the other thing] end ....
```

Replace your `count(1) = 0` with an `exists` condition - the difference is that there's no aggregation involved.